# Remove specific folders from a list in python?

Tags: python

I'm listing all files within a folder with `os.listdir` and was wondering how I would run a loop to remove any folders, aka strings within that list that don't end with .exe, .jpg, and so on.

Comment: Folders do not have .exe at end. you talking about removing files?

Comment: Use `os.path.isdir()` to check if a pathname is a directory or not.

Comment: It's perilous to rely upon file extensions telling you if something is a folder or not. That's not very reliable, as you can have folders with extensions and files that don't have them.

Answer (score 1):

I won't code the complete solution for you, but here are the components you need to get coding yourself.

1. `os.listdir` to list the files (you already figured this out)
2. `os.path.isfile` in order to not delete directories that could have weird names with extensions
3. `os.path.split` in order to get the extension of a file
4. `os.remove` to remove a file.

(I'm assuming you want to remove files, not folders. If you really want to remove folders, use `os.path.isdir` instead of `os.path.isfile`.)

Comment: `os.path.join` too

Comment: @SayandipDutta I don't think it's needed. You already have the filename before you split, no need to join again.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say that your list is

```py
>>> mylist
['hello.exe', 'abc.jpg', 'that', 'bro']
```

and you want to remove `that` and `bro` file because they do not have `.jpg` and `.exe` extension. So we use `del` operator from Python.

This is the code:

```py
>>> for i in range(len(mylist)):
...    if not (".exe" in mylist[i] or ".jpg" in mylist[i]):
...       del mylist[i]
...       i = i-1
```

And now if we check `mylist` output is

```py
>>> mylist
['hello.exe', 'abc.jpg']
```

Generally to remove files from your computer, you have to use `os.remove`. So you can try

```py
 location = "/home/User/Documents" #your path to in which you want to del file
 for i in range(len(mylist)):
    if not (".exe" in mylist[i] or ".jpg" in mylist[i]):
       os.remove(mylist[i])
       del mylist[i]
       i = i-1
```